# Как получить первичный session_id пользователя в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть 2 сервиса, назовем auth и school. Auth отвечает только за аутентификацию, другого функционала в нем нет.

School авторизует пользователя через auth сервис (редиректит туда по нажатию на логин, пользователь возвращается обратно с токеном). В school также передается session_id, чтобы логаутить именно эту сессию по логауту на auth сервисе (через http запроы сервер-сервер).

Когда юзер нажимает на логаут на auth, помимо удаления сессии на auth сервисе, рассылаются запросы по другим сервисам с session_id. Но сессия имеет свойство регенерации и изменения ID, поэтому если после изменения ID сессии нажать на выход на auth сервисе, то запрос на другие сессии будет передан с ID уже новой сессии и сессия на стороне другого сервиса не удалится, что оставит пользователя в системе, что является багом.
Аналогичная ситуация и с другой стороны — там тоже лара и тоже сессии (на school).

Comment: тебе номер сессии узнать?

Comment: @Bloom да, т.е. ID самой первой сессии, которая создалась сервером при входе юзера в аккаунт

Comment: http://tradebenefit.ru/chto-takoe-sessii-v-php

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session